# Get ReactiveVar in anonymous function

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I am using meteor reactive-var package. How can i get reactive variable in a anonymous function that is defined in templates's js file?
viewer.js:

```js
Template.viewer.helpers({
    counter: function () {
        return Template.instance().counter.get();
    }
});

Template.viewer.onCreated(function() {
    this.counter =  new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.viewer.onRendered(function(e){
    viewerRendered();
});

function getCounter() {
    // !!Return reactive counter variable
}

function viewerRendered() {
    var counter = getCounter();
    $(document).trigger("ViewerCreated",counter);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the current template in an external function through the `onRendered()` callback, you have multiple ways:

1. Using the external function as a direct callback :

   ```
   Template.viewer.onRendered(viewerRendered)

   function viewerRendered() {
     let currentTemplate = this
     //...
   }
   ```
2. Passing the current template as parameter :

   ```
   Template.viewer.onRendered(function() {
     viewerRendered(this)
   })

   function viewerRendered(currentTemplate) {
     //...
   ```

JavaScript functions are quite flexible since `this` is dynamic, there is other ways to access the data.
The two above are simple use-cases.

You may do whatever you want with the template such as accessing its [data](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_data), using [subscriptions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe)...